# Xamarin Android, background tag in multiple layouts causing crashes on device

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm trying to figure out how to handle the issue where having `android:background="@drawable/bg"` in multiple layouts is causing a crash due to, what I assume, is a memory leak. I have 3 images I change between displaying on certain screens.

I use `StartActivity(intent)` to transition to another activity and within the `OnCreate()` method I set the content view to the needed axml layout. However in doing this I have created an issue now where if I have 2 views with background images, the app crashes trying to load the second one. Is there something I need to do to tell the app to remove unused assets from memory or is my method of rendering the layout wrong?

Something to note also is that the app runs perfectly fine on the emulator, but crashes when deployed to the device.

here is the exact error message: `Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>`